# Unable to upload photo from Angular 8 to Laravel : "Call to a member function extension() on null" error

Tags: angular, typescript, laravel-5, file-upload

In my application : Angular 8 font end and Laravel 5.8 back end. I need to upload photo. I am following this tutorial : [ACADE MIND](https://academind.com/learn/angular/snippets/angular-image-upload-made-easy/#select-a-file).

**My template code** :

```
 <input  *ngIf="photoEdit" enctype="multipart/form-data" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>
 <button *ngIf="photoEdit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" (click)="onUpload()"> Save</button>
 <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" (click)="editPhoto()">Change Photo</button>
```

In the below method :

```
public onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.selectedFile);
  }
```

It is showing that file has been selected in the console log.

**onUpload() method :**

```
onUpload() {
    // this.http is the injected HttpClient
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('photo', this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name);
    // this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo/upload', { 'photo' : this.selectedFile }, this.authService.getHeader())
    //   .subscribe(event => {
    //     console.log(event);
    //   });
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo/upload', uploadData, this.authService.getHeader())
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
      });
  }
```

**getHeader()**

```
public getHeader() {
    var token: string;
    token = "bearer" + this.getToken();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': token
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
  }
```

I am getting :

```
   error : "Call to a member function extension() on null"
```

Photo upload from postman is working fine. In the server, i have printed the entire request. Below is the server log :

```
[Tue Nov 26 07:34:27 2019] Log In
[Tue Nov 26 07:34:34 2019] POST /api/photo/upload HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
Authorization:   bearereyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDczMjA2NywiZXhwIjoxNTc0NzM1NjY3LCJuYmYiOjE1NzQ3MzIwNjcsImp0aSI6IlhCQVR4YnlpVG
t5dzlha3IiLCJzdWIiOjQsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.Ul7eztDS024iN2AMgzwsHUiu4R4gcQctqtHnGftYaNw
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  39015
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:          http://localhost:4200
Referer:         http://localhost:4200/profile
Sec-Fetch-Mode:  cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:  cross-site
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36

------WebKitFormBoundaryvkYLBOFceCLCopiW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="3_4_5.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

**Server Side function:**

```
    public function upload(request $request)
        {
            error_log($request);
            $extension = $request->file('photo')->extension();

            if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
                error_log("FILE");
            }
            $fileName = "logedUserName";
            $fileName =  $fileName . "." . $extension;
            $savedPhotoName = $request->photo->storeAs('public', $fileName);
            return $savedPhotoName;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Laravel function to actually return an error on empty uploads like this;

```
public function upload(request $request)
{
    // Do we have a file?
    if ($request->hasFile("photo")) {
        error_log("Error::: No file provided in upload");
        return "error_no_file";
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Validate the file is what you want (size, mime type, etc.)

        $file = $request->file("photo");
        $filename = "loggedUserName-" . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // save to storage/app/photos
        $path = $file->storeAs("photos", $filename);

        // Return the path
        return $path;
    }
}
```

Then as a best guess try to either remove the 'Content-Type' header or set it explicitly to 'multipart/form-data' rather than 'application/json' in your **getHeader()**

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the reason, it is due to "Content-Type" mismatch. To do contrast, i have uploaded two server logs.

**1. Log with Problem**

```
`[Tue Nov 26 07:34:27 2019] Log In
[Tue Nov 26 07:34:34 2019] POST /api/photo/upload HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json, text/plain,
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
Authorization:`   `bearereyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDczMjA2NywiZXhwIjoxNTc0NzM1NjY3LCJuYmYiOjE1NzQ3MzIwNjcsImp0aSI6IlhCQVR4YnlpVGt5dzlha3IiLCJzdWIiOjQsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.Ul7eztDS024iN2AMgzwsHUiu4R4gcQctqtHnGftYaNw`
`Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  39015
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:          http://localhost:4200
Referer:         http://localhost:4200/profile
Sec-Fetch-Mode:  cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:  cross-site
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36`
```

`------WebKitFormBoundaryvkYLBOFceCLCopiW
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="3_4_5.png"
    Content-Type: image/png`

If we inspect the log, there is type mismatch in "Content-Type:".  Here content type is :

```
Content-Type:    application/json
```

The reason behind this, in time of sending JWT Token as header, i have given content type "Content-Type:    application/json".
After changing the content type, it is working. I have written new method with no content type.

```
public getHeaderFile() {
    var token: string;
    token = "bearer" + this.getToken();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': token
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
  }
```

**2. working log**

```
[Tue Nov 26 11:09:19 2019] Log In
[Tue Nov 26 11:09:35 2019] POST /api/photo/upload HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8
Authorization:   bearereyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDc0NDk2MCwiZXhwIjoxNTc0NzQ4NTYwLCJuYmYiOjE1NzQ3NDQ5NjAsImp0aSI6IkZxSWJnclFSNG
JUdW1SMEYiLCJzdWIiOjQsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.gk-byS9kuyEzNQsHkxSgb6IlmjZm6suTgD5DLzRd2KI
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  2051
Content-Type:    multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzfjTeLXzaEUrfSO1
Host:            127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:          http://localhost:4200
Referer:         http://localhost:4200/profile
Sec-Fetch-Mode:  cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:  cross-site
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36


[Tue Nov 26 11:09:36 2019] E:\ProgramsFiles\xampp\tmp\phpB2DE.tmp
[Tue Nov 26 11:09:36 2019] FILE RECEIVED!
```

Here content type :

```
Content-Type:    multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzfjTeLXzaEUrfSO1
```